# Directive not working when separate module created

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

## Background

I'm building an angular app with a file structure recommended [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure).
A quick rundown is that every part of your app is split into mini modules to keep it maintainable. I thought this was a great Idea because pervious apps I've worked on have huge code base that was difficult to decipher.

## Problem

I have some controllers, services and routes and was just starting to build my first directive of the app when I kept getting this error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- navDirDirective

I've read through the [unknown provider error doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) but wasn't able to find anything.

## Code

Here is my code

### Directive

```
angular.module('myAppNavbarDirective', []).directive('navDir', ['', function(){
  // Runs during compile
  return {
      template: 'test if the dir is working'
  };
}]);
```

### Module

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",   [
                                    'ui.bootstrap',
                                    'ngAnimate',
                                    'myAppRouter',
                                    'myAppHomeCtrl',
                                    'myAppHomeService',
                                    'myAppNavbarDirective'
                                ]);
```

### Index (snippet)

```
<!-- Navigation Bar-->
<nav-dir></nav-dir>
<!-- some code -->
<!-- Angular Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/navigation-bar/navbarDirective.js"></script>
```

## Question

As you can see I've created a module with a directive and then put that module in my main module script and all-so called it on my index.html. Why am I getting this error, maybe I've missed something that I just cant see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because you're trying to inject a service by the name `''` (empty string) into your directive.

Should be (remove empty string injection)

```
angular.module('myAppNavbarDirective', []).directive('navDir', [function(){
  // Runs during compile
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'test if the dir is working'
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Not double checking intelisence was my problem haha. Great catch!